# avconv equivalent to Ffmpeg's scale2ref?

Tags: libav

Using a filter_complex in ffmpeg with `'[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]'`, where I'm overlaying a png on top of a video and scaling down to the size of the video. Is there an avconv equivalent to use scale2ref like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an avconv equivalent to use scale2ref like this?

The answer is simply "no". Use `ffmpeg` instead.